# Check if a function does not exist in chai

Tags: solidity, testing, chai

I'm using chai to test my contracts.
I have a test that calls a function that does not exist in that contract.
This is the contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.13;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20BurnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/security/PausableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/utils/math/SafeMathUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/utils/cryptography/ECDSAUpgradeable.sol";

contract Token is
    Initializable,
    ERC20Upgradeable,
    ERC20BurnableUpgradeable,
    PausableUpgradeable,
    OwnableUpgradeable
{
    //This function gets called by the TokenFactory contract
    function initialize(string memory _name, string memory _symbol)
        external
        initializer
    {
        __ERC20_init(_name, _symbol);
        __ERC20Burnable_init();
        __Pausable_init();
        __Ownable_init();
    }
}
```

This is the test.js

```
it("assure the version() function is not available in first contract", async function() {
        const addressOfFirstToken = await tokenFactory.getTokenAddress(0);
        const addressOfSecondToken = await tokenFactory.getTokenAddress(1);
        const firstToken = await Token.attach(addressOfFirstToken);
        const secondToken = await Token.attach(addressOfSecondToken);
        
        expect(await firstToken.version()).to.throw(TypeError);
})
```

This is the message it pops up when I run

```
npx hardhat test
```

```
  1) Factory token is upgradeable
       assure the version() function is not available in first contract:
     TypeError: firstToken.version is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/createFactoryUpgradeable.js:68:33)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20220016, "You need to pass a function to chai, but your code is passing the result of calling the function instead."

This worked for me:

```
expect(await firstToken.version()).to.throw("firstToken.version is not a function");
```